# Obfuscating c# code not the assembly

Tags: c#, obfuscation

Is there a way to obfuscate c# code (visual studio solution ) so that if soem one even get the project could not understand it ?
note:  I'm not talking bout obfuscating assembly/Executable here..

Comment: How about generate the DLLs/programs, run a regular obfuscating program on them, then use something like ILSpy (but automated) to generate code from them.

Comment: @aitzaz this make no sens.

Comment: An alternative would be to get your past self to write it. I often don't know what the heck I was doing! :)

Comment: LOL i have to deliver the code but want to make it difficult to read because this is my final year project and university said i must deliver the code too .does it make sense now?serge

Comment: @george if i do so that code will not recompile..

Comment: Why not? It should do.

Comment: If you need to deliver code to the university then there must be a reason for it (maybe they want to ensure you're using coding standards for example?), whatever reasons those are, by obfuscating it you're probably going to cause issues for them and in turn for you.

Comment: its a rule that everyone must submit code after completing project but i want to launch my project on my own..that's why i wanna do this..it will not cause any problem..

Comment: @george i tried that nut the obfuscator i used did add some chines characters in the code ..VS says they are unidentifiable..:-D

Comment: You might find that they have some ownership rights over the code...

Comment: This is pakistan there are no ownership rights here..LOL..BTW can we stick to the question here???

Comment: You have some answers - if they are not helpful comment on them rather than pasting the same response to each.

Answer (score 5):

I've not seen anything commercially, but you could probably write your own application to do this. I actually know someone once did this for some ASPX pages that were being deployed.

You'd have to take similar steps:

1. Rename all local variables to very similar names B_**__*0, B***_0 etc.
2. Rename all internal and private methods/classes and all their references.
3. Encode all your strings.
4. Insert random code/calls that don't do anything.

Consider why you want this though... It means:

- You can't ever view your own code. You'll have the original somewhere - why not just password protect it?
- You're going to screw with any source control you're running.
- You're going to have some crazy "process my entire solution" everytime you save/publish it?

In short it's probably not a good idea, which is why you probably can't find a commercial solution.

Comment: LOL i have to deliver the code but want to make it difficult to read because this is my final year project and university said i must deliver the code too

Answer (score 3):

Close the door and windows tight.

Disconnect your computer from Internet during the developement.

Obfuscate your assemblies when your done.

Save them a a disk.

Burn down your computer.

Keep hitting your head onto a wall until you fergot why you're doing it.

There, you're safe, nobody will ever have the same exact source.
I hope your application has no bug, though.

Comment: Yes, this is totally not helpfull but it was worth it.

Answer (score 0):

A more sensible alternative might be to just encrypt your hard drive using something like
[BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/products/features/bitlocker) or 
[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

Comment: LOL i have to deliver the code but want to make it difficult to read because this is my final year project and university said i must deliver the code too

Answer (score 0):

1. Obfuscate the dll
2. Use a decompiler like ILSpy and decompile the dll

This way you get obfuscated C# code.